# Android:how to set Webpage Full in Webview? by Set Zoom Decrease?or any?

Tags: android, android-widget, webview

In My WebView i load the WebPage but the Page are not set as Full page by Scroll we can show whole page as Default.  I want to show Whole page Horizontaily Full View Its Does't matter if webpage will Containt show Small. so how can i achive this goal?

Comment: @Upvoters-Atleast edit the question so that it could be readable and then upvote please.